# How to validate user input a number and the number greater than 0

Tags: c++

I'm trying to validate user input that user must enter number and it must be greater than 0, the validation of only numbers I got it working; however, I can't seem to incorporate the validation of greater than 0

```
float income;
cout << "How much did you earn last year: ";

    //validating imput for income
    while(!(cin >> income))
    {
         char ch;
         cin.clear();
         cout << "Sorry, number must be biger than \"0\" \n"
              << "How much did you make last year: ";
         while(cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the condition to the `while`, and handle it in the loop:

```
while ( !(cin >> income) || income < 0.0 ) {
    if ( !cin )
        //  Clean up input stream...
    else
        //  Must be negative number... 
}
```